# How to wait for the child's termination and the signals at the same time?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals, fork

The application I am dealing with is multi-threaded. Each thread has a code segment which calls `fork()`, and in turn the child calls `execlp()`. But no two threads execute that code segment simultaneously (synchronized with mutex_locks). I need to wait for the child completion to proceed further. This is generally achieved by `wait*()` system calls. But in my case, I can't be blocked for whole 1 minute (expected child execution time) since I need to respond to the signals sent by main() thread. Below is a minimal thread function that helps in understanding the execution flow

```
void thread_func()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&fork_lock);

    pid_t fk_return = fork();

    if (fk_return < 0) {
        goto thread_quit;
    }
    else if (fk_return == 0) {
        // Call execlp(). It will terminate after a minute or so.
    }

    /* Wait for child termination and signal */

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&fork_lock);

    /* Non critical code segment */

    thread_quit:
    return NULL;
}
```

So, how can I wait for both child termination and signals sent by main() at the same time ?

Comment: Mixing `fork` and threads is fraught with peril. Why are you doing that?

Comment: "After a fork() in a multithreaded program, the child can safely call only async-signal-safe functions (see signal-safety(7)) until such time as it calls execve(2)." From the man page of ``fork()``. It sounds like, its the same with the C also. But luckily I am calling exec* programs just after the call to fork(). Sorry, my program logic is like that :(

Comment: Some variables required to execute the command are not known prior (e.g, port to which socket binded). By the time I know them, the application would have opened multiple threads. I dont think there is any way around this.